# How can I test my tls implementation written using HTTP component

Tags: ssl, testing, wireshark, tls1.2

For my current project i need to implement http over tls at client ,for this i need a local server able to simulate this . is there any online or offline tool. which i can use and and see the handshake in wireshark .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For watching the TLS handshake you might not get far enough with wireshark. For such kind of monitoring you would ensure the security is low enough for wireshark to be able getting the session key from watching the handshake for decoding the later parts. Thus, you need to avoid any forward secrecy.

Otherwise any (https) server that is accessible (and willing to talk) to your client will do.

In case you are in an environment that is supported (e.g. any unix/linux), you might try using `openssl`. It allows setting up a server that will do handshake. And it will log the handshake such that you will be able looking at what is going on. This will eliminate the need for using wireshark for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this you need a Web Server accepting connection over TLS.I have achieved this on Apache Tomcat web Server.

TLS configuration needs to be done in the server.xml file present in config directory of Tomcat webserver. Connector tag needs to be added in the server.xml file that contains information like
TLS version to be used, port, List of supported Cipher Suites, Keystore path and password, Truststore path and password.

Any regular Rest client can be used to make a call like Postman client. But to use that over TLS/SSL certificate is needed to be installed in Chrome browser.

Hope this answers your doubt.